# Firebase security rules not working

Tags: firebase-security

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the users who are under the **users** node only have access to both read and write and those who are not under the **users** node only have access to read. I wrote this rule but it says some error like **Admin: false**.

Comment: "It says some error" is rather unclear. Please edit your question to include the precise error message you get, and the code that triggers that error message. I also recommend reading about [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this is often the best way to ensure you get help with code related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most common usage of firebase real time database rule if user is exist can read and write and if user not exists than only read the database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```